# Use of internal rules in Rust macros 2.0

Tags: macros, rust

I cannot understand where lazy-static's [`@TAIL`](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/lazy-static.rs/blob/af6a4697f65d596bafbad66650998a1d6e05157a/src/lib.rs#L134) and [`@MAKE`](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/lazy-static.rs/blob/af6a4697f65d596bafbad66650998a1d6e05157a/src/lib.rs#L133) have been defined and their particular use cases.

If I've understood [internal rules](https://danielkeep.github.io/tlborm/book/pat-internal-rules.html) correctly, the primary usage of `@as_expr` in the example is to hide `as_expr!` (or in general, previously defined macros) from being exported i.e. it's a way of altering the global macro namespace. Following that, then `@TAIL` or `@MAKE` should already be a macro while I cannot find them in the [lazy_static source](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/lazy-static.rs/tree/master/src).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *linked* to the definitions.  `@TAIL` is right there three lines down on 137, `@MAKE` is on 162.

`@name` is not special in any way whatsoever.  There is absolutely no special behaviour.  It's just a sequence of tokens that cannot show up in "normal" code, and is thus unlikely to be accidentally matched to other rules.  `@as_expr` does not hide an `as_expr!` macro, it's used *instead* of defining a publicly visible `as_expr!` macro.

Comment: I see! so I guess by convention people use `@name`. It can be any sequence of tokens then. Thanks for your explanation and your little book of macros is of great help btw. I wish it had little more explanations, examples and references.